# IE 10 Keeps refreshing my website

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, meta

Goodday!

Our client has the problem that IE keeps refreshing when he goes to "http://blauwzaam.nl".

Somehow i cant reproduce this problem on my own computer. If I check my network activity, the 'html5player.js' does allot of AJAX calls. Can this be the problem?

[Edit]

I noticed that when i use "Inspec Element" in chrome a couple of times, the page breaks. Also, when i resize it.. it refreshes, could that be a problem?

Comment: Have you maybe done a virus scan on their PC? If you can't reproduce, then it's unlikely a direct website error. Does the error persist on other websites?

Comment: That's a possibility, but i noticed that when i use "Inspec Element" in chrome a couple of times, the page breaks. Also, when i resize it.. it refreshes, could that be a problem?